# How do I convey that I'm ready to pay my tab in Greece?

Tags: greece, restaurants

I'm 15 days into a 30-day trip all across Greece (Athens, northern mainland, islands). Everything has been great except the long wait each time we are ready to pay our bill when we're out to eat or for drinks. In America, cleared plates or a credit card/cash sitting on the table is an indication that we are ready to leave. Here it seems they are in no rush at all. We've even waited 20 minutes (they weren't busy). They print the tickets and bring them out immediately but take much longer to take payment. Multiple times we've had to walk to them - which feels a bit rude.

**My question**
How do I more clearly indicate that I am ready to pay and leave?
**or**
Am I just being an impatient American not attuned to the Mediterranean pace of life?

Comment: If everything else fails, standing up and donning outerwear has always worked for me.

Comment: I've noticed this is true in Greek restaurants in North America in some cases, too (I had it happen to me at a Greek restaurant in Toronto's Greek Village a few years ago).  The solution is the same.  :)

Comment: It's never rude to come up to the bar to pay your bill, even in the US.

Comment: One of the biggest complaints among fellow recently-arrived expats in Europe when I first moved there was the glacial pace of the service.  Some of that may have been in fact related to glacial pace of the service, but much of it was also that they hadn't gotten used to the fact that it's generally necessary to attract the attention of the staff if you want anything, including to pay.  Once you become accustomed to this, everything works much more smoothly.

Comment: @HenningMakholm what if it's summer?  If I'm having trouble attracting the attention of my waiter, I sometimes take my wallet in my hand and walk over (especially if the trouble is caused by the waiter's attention being given to a conversation with colleagues).

Comment: @phoog That's good if you have enough of an overview of the place to know where the register is. Unfortunately my memory for faces is terrible, so I'm rarely sure *which* waiter's attention to try to catch. Thus the more convenient convoluted strategies.

Comment: The phrase in Greek is "To logariasMO, parakalo."

Comment: I'd say it as 'To lohariasMO' - it doesn't have a hard G.  There's a law that you must be provided with a receipt, so some places (cafes especially) will provide the receipt with each stage of your order. If you want attention, wave at them or walk up to the counter.

Comment: Even quicker way to get bill is to make a writing gesture, with your hand up in the air when you and your waiter have eye contact.

Comment: As a mnemonic for remembering the phrase, you might note its similarity to _logarithm_, which also is something to do with counting (both words have common ancestors). BTW, while the _gamma_ is not the hard _Jee_ of English, it's going a bit far to turn it into an _Aitch_ - let's split the difference and go with _logharismo_.

Comment: If you start leaving the restaurant they usually hurry after you with the bill :)

Comment: If they don't show up with the bill after 15 minutes you're legally allowed to leave.

Comment: @walen Really? Do you have a source for that? Based on my experience, waiting longer than 15 minutes to pay, in Greece, is normal... A friend of mine and I were even joking that the cause of the Greek crisis is simply that customers leave without paying, because the wait is too long and frustrating...

Comment: For US citizens dining in a european restaurant, especially in the southern parts, is definitely a different experience. It is not uncommon to spend 3 hours in a restaurant for dinner in Greece. The waiters will react more to hand signs and eye contact. Long conversations during the dinner are normal. As opposed to the US the waiters are not staying in contact with you all the time to provide a great service and get a bigger tip.

Comment: In many places in the world, bringing the bill is considered rude unless you ask for it. The implication is that they are rushing you.

Comment: @FabioTurati I can say with certainty that it was a joke, specifically a reference to [this](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/legally-allowed-to-leave)

Comment: @HenningMakholm simply attract the attention of any waiter/waitress, if it's the wrong one they will send the right one over. Or good-naturedly bawl their name across the premises and point at you.  : )

Answer (score 132, accepted):

In many parts of Europe it is considered rude for a restaurant to bring you your bill without being asked. Meals are expected to be relaxed, unhurried affairs, and for a restaurant to bring the bill, or ask for payment, without being asked is seen as them trying to hurry you out.

As such it is absolutely expected that you ask for the bill, or if you already have the bill ask to pay it. Attract the waiter's attention. This is more acceptable in Europe than the US, because generally a waiter won't disturb you unless they think you want something. (The endless "is everything alright - how is the food?" questions from North American waiters still faintly irritates some of us European expats.) If language is a problem, then the universal "mime writing something on your hand" usually works. Have a look at what others are doing - they may be paying at the counter (though this is pretty rare in Europe). If you are in a hurry, ask for the bill as soon as your last item is brought, and ask to pay as soon as the bill is brought.

If you are paying by cash, then leaving the cash on the table is also acceptable

Comment: I always thought the "mime writing on your hand" thing was a bit strange, but I've yet to find a country it doesn't work (having now used it in several dozen, in all continents).

Comment: Everywhere I go I found that a raised hand "counting money" means getting the bill (europe at least, germany and adjacent countries).

Comment: "faintly" is understating the level of irritation, depending perhaps on the server's demeanor, and this is coming from someone who was born and raised in the US.  In addition to miming with the hand, I have occasionally, when in a hurry, at least, employed the tactic of getting up with my wallet in my hand and approaching the server or, if one is visible, the cash register/till.  I've never noticed that to be received poorly by the staff.

Comment: I wouldn't say that paying at the counter is rare, but perhaps it is in posher places.

Comment: Going to the counter to pay is pretty common, especially when you're in a hurry.  Nobody will be offended, and it saves a roundtrip with change/card terminal/etc.

Comment: Paying at the counter is not rare in Europe, in fact, in  many Italian restaurants, it is the norm

Comment: How do you avoid paying at the counter when you have to put in your PIN?

Comment: I always pay at the counter In the Netherlands and Belgium and see a lot of people doing so as well. If you want to use PIN, you'll actually have to pay at the counter in most places. Unless it has a wireless PIN device.

Comment: @curiousdannii it is rare, but some have a wireless PIN device.

Comment: the "write in hand with invisible pen" is probably the best advice. it goes back to the "ancient days" ( pre 2000) where you payed with visa by signing.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid - Rare? Ok I live in the UK which has a lot of differences to continental Europe, but pretty much every restaurant here has a wireless card machine.

Comment: @AndyT 'Rare' might not have been the good word. Though it seems more and more places are getting wireless card machines.

Comment: Whatever you do, though, don't snap your fingers!

Comment: Born in the US and I've spent hardly any time outside it, and *The endless "is everything alright - how is the food?" questions* always annoy me a great deal. Even more annoying is an overeager backwaiter grabbing my plate to take it away when there's still food on it! I've never seen these as attempts at politeness but instead attempts to get me to leave so someone else can be seated.

Comment: In the UK, literally everywhere will have a wireless pin device. The only restaurants that require you to pay at the counter are either fast-dining places or the type of incredibly old-school clubs where it is expected that the host will pay for everyone, and the guests will be given menus without prices. Paying at a counter means they have no chance to see the final total, either.

Comment: As a Greek, I would only add that _sometimes_ if the business notices you've finished eating some time ago they might use approaches such as "can I take some of the plates that you're already done with" or "can we offer you a complimentary dessert" as a polite poke. But it can also happen as a matter of course.

Answer (score 28):

In Greece you should just signal to the waiter. Either raise your hand or do what DJClayworth said. It is not uncommon for people to ask for extra plates (fries, tzatziki, feta etc.), so they will wait for you to tell them when you are ready to pay the bill. (Also in many restaurants when you signal for the bill they bring a dessert too!)

Comment: So you mean you won't get the ordered desert until you signal for the bill?

Comment: No you will get a FREE dessert.

Comment: I can verify. It is quite often (the default I would say) for dessert to come at the end of your meal for free -after you have paid-, as a 'thank you' from the restaurant.

Comment: What kind of desert is it usually? (e.g. ice cream, cake) Have never encountered this. :)

Comment: @kiradotee In Croatia, in the same region as Greece, a desert liquor (Kruškovac, Slivovitz, Grappa) is usually given free of charge.

Comment: @kiradotee It depends on the place and time of year. But in the summer usually the dessert is either fruit(watermelon,melon) or yogurt with honey. Or in some rare cases you could get a local desssert.

Comment: @kiradotee Whatever is local, Greece/Greek islands it's usually something like watermelon, as they are practically everywhere, or you may get a shot of the local spirit.  Even though you may be full, it's too tasty to pass up, so try to pay at the table and not look in a  rush.

Comment: So far desserts we've been gifted for free include: yogurt with nuts and honey, yogurt with beets, almond cake and other types of little cakes that I am unsure what flavor they were. :)

Comment: You can tell I love a good dessert, but in all the (more or less authentic) Greek restaurants I visited here in Germany the waiter brought a free [Ouzo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouzo) instead.

Comment: As a born and bred American, I frequently read the comments section of answers here on Travel and wonder why I haven't moved to Europe yet...

Answer (score 0):

That would apply if you were at an a' la carte restaurant. In general we raise our hand & say the bill please (cos as Giorgio said sometimes we raise our hand & order extra dishes etc). The best I've discussed with American friends is the body language, meaning from place to place things can be different from such things to greetings so feel free to ask.

Enjoy your holidays :)